Typing animation + continue on button press
I've been trying to create a simple animation using only js and html (and probably css if possible). Attached below is my code, and here's what I'm thinking of:
When I press the "click me" button, it will do a typing animation that types out "Lorem Ipsum". When it finishes typing, a button will show up underneath it to continue the dialogue. When you continue it, it prints out " Dolor sit amet.", but it just continues from the "Lorem Ipsum" text.
What I expected was that when I click "continue", it will print the text in a new line. I was also wondering if it's possible to also attach images midway through dialogue. For example, if I want to enrich the story by adding an image, I want the dialogue to continue typing and then under it there will be an image, followed by some dialogue again.
Basically, I was wondering if it's possible to do Start -> Continue button -> New Line -> Dialogue -> Image -> Dialogue -> Continue again


var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem Ipsum.';
var speed = 50;

function typingAnim() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typingAnim, speed);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("continueButton").style.display = "block";
  }
}

function continueTyping() {
  var otherText = ' Dolor sit amet.';
  document.getElementById("continueButton").style.display = "none";
  txt += otherText;
  i = txt.length - otherText.length;
  setTimeout(typingAnim, speed);
}
<button onclick="typingAnim()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<button id="continueButton" style="display: none;" onclick="continueTyping()">Continue</button>




You have to create a new paragraph when you want a new line, since appending to innerText of the same paragraph will continue the current line.


var txt = 'Lorem Ipsum.';
var speed = 50;
let dialog = document.getElementById("dialog")

function typingAnim(el = null, text = null, image = null) {
  el ??= document.getElementById("dialog").children[0]
  text ??= txt

  el.innerHTML += text.charAt(0);
  if(text.length > 1) {
    setTimeout(() => typingAnim(el, text.substring(1), image), speed);
  } 
  else if(image) {
    let imgEl = document.createElement('img')
    imgEl.src = image
    dialog.appendChild(imgEl)
  }
  
  document.getElementById("continueButton").style.display = "block";
}

function continueTyping() {
  var otherText = ' Dolor sit amet.';
  let newLine = document.createElement('p')
  dialog.appendChild(newLine)
  let image = "https://picsum.photos/50/50"
  setTimeout(() => typingAnim(newLine, otherText, image), speed);
}
<button onclick="typingAnim()">Click me</button>
<div id="dialog">
<p></p>
</div>
<button id="continueButton" style="display: none;" onclick="continueTyping()">Continue</button>



